# Could you not migrate programming questions to android.SE, please?

Tags: discussion, migration

We've just had [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/77391/how-to-inspect-http-requests-made-by-webviews) migrated to us by an SO moderator. The question is asking for advice on how to add logging to a `WebView`-based Android app. We don't deal with programming questions on android.SE, and most of our users are non-programmers, so this question is unlikely to receive a satisfactory answer there even if it were left open.

I can understand that there might have been a mistake made, as at first glance the question appears to be in a grey area. It looks like a pointer to Chrome Remote Debugging would be suitable. That's a tool primarily used for programming, so IMO that would be on-topic on Stack Overflow. It's also an Android tool occasionally used by end-users to examine web pages, just like Firefox's "inspect" feature is, so that would be just about on-topic on android.SE (bur possibly a duplicate: we have a small number of questions about Chrome Remote Debugging already).

However, in this case, the questioner's comments quite clearly indicate he's looking for a code solution to the problem.

> And yeah, the URL is not enough, and I prefer get if with `onLoadResource`

And,

> ok, but that looks like a debugging approach only. Is there a way to get it inside the application ?

Since the question can't be migrated twice, it's now likely to be closed, which gives the questioner a bad experience of the SE network, especially as the question was on the correct site in the first place. This is a reminder to everyone to be extra-careful when migrating questions. Even moderators should follow the rule of only migrating if you're also an active user on the target site (or have checked with that site's community in chat).

Comment: I had a similar thing happen to me. I asked a programming question here on SO, but it was migrated to android.SE. A few days later, I received a comment on my question from a mod at android.SE saying that my question was not suitable for android.SE, and to try SO... I never did get an answer to my question.

Comment: Can't you just reject the migration?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

I cleared the migration history on the original post, so if you delete the target it'll be like this never happened.

The original post was flagged by the asker themselves, who requested it be migrated. Not entirely sure why, or why a moderator accepted that, but that's what started this. We usually decline these flags, so this is probably just an honest mistake.

Comment: Although I am nowhere near getting moderator tools, I have so far found very little as to what you should/shouldn't do, apart from here on the meta itself.  Do you think there should be a post for moderators which links to questions like this and what to do in these situations?  I don't think moderators can be expected to read over the 5,770 posts currently on meta.